# How can I perform a zip compression that outputs binary, not a zip file?

Tags: javascript, zip, compression, jszip

### Use-case

- Compress a String to a binary ZIP blob
- The resulting ZIP should not resemble a ZIP file, but rather, result the result RAW binary stream ( should not have the .ZIP file folders/file envelope

Text String -> Compress -> RAW binary Blob

I was reading about JSZip that seems quite comprehensive, but, it seems the output is always a ZIP file ( including the folder/files envelope ) where what I needed is the RAW binary blob for the iput string ( not associated to any file name ).

Is there any way to achieve that using Client Side JavaScript ? ( using JSZip or others )

Comment: If it doesn't have the header, it's not ZIP format. It sounds like you just want to use a compression library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [zlib](https://nodejs.org/api/zlib.html). `zlib.Deflate` will compress the data to a zlib stream. A zlib stream is the deflate compressed data with a two-byte header and a four-byte integrity check trailer. Six bytes is a tiny amount for the assurance of an integrity check, but if you want to even get rid of those, then you can use `zlib.DeflateRaw`.